# Facebook graph api : Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When, I follow to context in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview

request next url
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE-ID/feed?message=Hello&
fields=created_time,from,id,message&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
this url but, I've got this error

{
"error": {
"message": "Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 190,
"error_subcode": 2069032,
"is_transient": false,
"error_user_title": "\uc0ac\uc6a9\uc790 \uc561\uc138\uc2a4 \ud1a0\ud070\uc740 \uc9c0\uc6d0\ub418\uc9c0 \uc54a\uc2b5\ub2c8\ub2e4",
"error_user_msg": "\uc0c8\ub85c\uc6b4 \ud398\uc774\uc9c0 \uacbd\ud5d8\uc744 \ud638\ucd9c\ud558\ub824\uba74 \ud398\uc774\uc9c0 \uc561\uc138\uc2a4 \ud1a0\ud070\uc774 \ud544\uc694\ud569\ub2c8\ub2e4.",
"fbtrace_id": "As5x9CgoRLrIIBK9yTO1mRv"
}
}

What is mean of "Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token" and how can I solve this problem?

I've tried changing PAGE_ID to the page name or facebook page id.

Comment: Did you replace `ACCESS-TOKEN` with an actual access token?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. And I tried generate other ACCESS-TOKEN. But, it also doesn't work.

Comment: _"request next url"_ - are you making a GET request? If you want to create a post, it needs to be POST.

Comment: Thank you! I just typed url into chrome address bar One more question, if I post this url and I return 
"(#210) A page access token is required to request this resource". What are the required permissions?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens